# Is Reference type in C++ a POD type?

Tags: c++

Is Reference type in C++ a POD type too?
Is `int&` is a POD type? and what about

```
struct Q { int& i; }
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: you can check for yourself using the type trait `std::is_pod`

Comment: I can pass a non-POD type by reference.  A reference is a method of passing variables; not a type.

Answer (score 9):

No.

The only way to set a member that references something is via a user-declared constructor, so therefore, your structure is non-POD.

**Update:**
The answer is still no.

The C++03 standard specifies that "*A POD-struct is an aggregate class that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and ...*" (C++03 standard sect. 9 para 5).

In C++11, a POD-struct "*is a class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class, and ...*" and a standard-layout class "*has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference*" (C++11 standard sect. 9 para. 6-9).

I parse those phrases that end with "or reference" to immediately mean that a POD class cannot contain non-static data members that are of any reference type. The lack of a comma before the "or reference" does give way to other interpretations (e.g., it's a reference to a non-POD class that makes the reference bad, not a reference *per se*), but I'm sticking with my interpretation.

Comment: Not really, aggregate initialization can be used to set that member, although that does not mean that it is a POD (it isn't)

Comment: That lack of a comma is a nasty one. Not as nasty as taking the commas out of "I like cooking, my family, and my friends", but still nasty.

Answer (score 6):

There is a standard way (using C++11) to determine that at compile time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Q
{
    int& i;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_pod<int>::value << "\t";
    std::cout << std::is_pod<int&>::value << "\t";
    std::cout << std::is_pod<Q>::value << "\n";
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/PECzfT

The output will be 1 0 0, so **no** a reference to int is not POD.

Comment: There's a risk to relying on a specific compiler, since compilers often have bugs in them and the libraries sometimes don't work 100% correctly.  That said, thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 4):

A POD type is any intrinsic type or aggregate of intrinsic types (basically, anything that does not have a custom constructor, destructor, copy-constructor, copy-assignment operator, nor non-static pointer-to-member types (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c))

Since a member that references something must be set via a custom constructor, it would violate the first requirement.  In short, a struct that declares a reference type as a member is not a POD type.

Comment: As mentioned in a different comment, you don't need a user defined constructor, aggregate initialization can be used to initialize the reference. But that does not change the real answer: it is not a POD

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas True, but the effect of that is, in effect, implementing a custom copy-constructor (which violates the 3rd criteria).

Comment: The one case that the reference inhibits is not any of the constructions, but the assignment operator. Again, this does not make the answer incorrect, just slightly imprecise.