# How to correctly forward/wrap static_cast?

Tags: c++, generic-programming, static-cast, perfect-forwarding

Basicly, I need a `static_cast` function wrapper to use as a predicate (for conversion), since `static_cast` directly is not usable in this way. Lambda is not preferred this time. My implemention:

```
template<typename T> 
struct static_cast_forward{
  template<class U>
  T operator()(U&& u) const {
    return static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(u));
  }
};
```

First, while I do have a fundamental understanding of rvalue references, etc. I want to verify if this is the correct way to implement this forward/wrapper ?

Second, to ask if any `std` or `boost` library already provide this functionality ?

Extra: would you forward other casts in the same way ?

**ACTUAL CASE:**

My actual case is to use with `boost::range`, something like:

```
//auto targetsRange = mixedRange | boost::adaptors::filtered(TYPECHECK_PRED) | boost::adaptors::transformed(static_cast_forward<TARGET_PTR_TYPE>());
```

**WORKING EXAMPLES:**

```
#include <algorithm>
template<typename T>
struct static_cast_forward {
    template<class U>
    T operator()(U&& u) const {
        return static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(u));
    }
};

//example 1:

void test1() {
    std::vector<double> doubleVec{1.1, 1.2};
    std::vector<int> intVec;
    std::copy(doubleVec.begin(), doubleVec.end(), intVec.end());//not ok (compiles, but gives warning) 
    std::transform(doubleVec.begin(), doubleVec.end(), std::back_inserter(intVec), static_cast_forward<int>()); //ok
}

//example 2:

struct A {
    virtual ~A() {} 
};

struct B : public A {
};

struct C : public A {
};

void test2() {
    std::vector<A*> vecOfA{ new B, new B};
    std::vector<B*> vecOfB;
    //std::transform(vecOfA.begin(), vecOfA.end(), std::back_inserter(vecOfB), static_cast<B*>); //not ok: syntax error..
    std::transform(vecOfA.begin(), vecOfA.end(), std::back_inserter(vecOfB), static_cast_forward<B*>() ); //ok
}
```

Comment: Show an example how you want to use `static_cast_forward::operator()`. The way you use `std::forward` is not correct. Template argument should be specified.

Comment: Basically your function should look like `T&& operator()(U&& u) const { return std::forward<T>(u); }` `std::forward` does a static cast to `T&&` internally.

Comment: @George, you do cast non-pod types in, e.g., CRTP.

Comment: @Evg If you want to invoke ub. Note that references and pointers are pod types.

Comment: @George, pointers, but not references, `static_assert(!std::is_pod_v<int&>)`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144007/is-reference-type-in-c-a-pod-type

Comment: Ah damn, well thanks for correcting me :) "Also, you should never try and cast a type that is non pod and not a reference."

Comment: @George, I would also not attempt at casting `int&` to `long&`. ;)

Comment: @Evg an example could be to use with std::transform to convert one type container to another. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform. Im using this with boost::range.

Comment: Fixed the missing template argument to std::forward

Comment: Maybe you need this: `copy(make_move_iterator(bs.begin()), make_move_iterator(bs.end()), back_inserter(ds));`? Here `std::vector<B> bs{...};`, `std::vector<D> ds;` and `struct D` has constructor `D(B&&)`. This will move all `bs` into `ds`.

Answer (score 2):

**Addition after the question has been clarified.**

In both cases you don't need to `std::forward` anything, because there is nothing to move, you need just a cast. But if you want to generalize to movable types, too, then your implementation seems fine to me. Just don't call it `forward` because it is not a `forward`. As far as I know, there is nothing in `std` to mimic your `struct`.

So I would just add `test3()` that really needs moving:

```
struct B { };

struct D { 
    explicit D(B&&) { }   // Note: explicit!
};

void test3()
{
    std::vector<B> vb{B{}, B{}};
    std::vector<D> vd;

    // Won't compile because constructor is explicit
    //std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(vb.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(vb.end()), std::back_inserter(vd));

    // Works fine
    std::transform(std::make_move_iterator(vb.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(vb.end()), std::back_inserter(vd), static_cast_forward<D>());
}
```

**Answer before question was clarified.**

If I correctly understood your intention, then this is what you want:

```
template<typename T>
struct static_cast_forward {
    template<class U>
    decltype(auto) operator()(U&& u) const
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<U>)
            return static_cast<T&>(u);
        else
            return static_cast<T&&>(u);
    }
};
```

Then you have:

```
struct B { };
struct D : B { };

void foo() {
    D d;
    static_cast_forward<B> scf_as_B;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(scf_as_B(D{})), B&&>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(scf_as_B(d)), B&>);
}
```

Comment: What I want is basic template for forwarding call of static_cast (since you cannot you use static_cast as a predicate directly).

Comment: Also are you sure that will work ? I believe static_cast returns a copy itself - so wouldn't it return a dangling reference then. eg. static_cast<int>(5) i believe returns a copy - and your else clause return &&. Please explain.

Comment: @darune `static_cast` is just a cast. In my view a *forwarding* function `foo()` should return `int&&` for `foo(5)`, as well as `B&&` for `foo(B{})`. Yes, it can easily become a dangling reference, but this is not a problem of this function, but a problem of a user who uses it incorrectly. You should really present a particular use case you have in mind. Probably, we have an XY problem here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: maybe you misunderstand the question then, but please explain why you think it is NOT possible to make a fully functioning forward to static_cast ? one that mirrors the underlying call and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: @darune, I just don't understand the requirements. What this function is supposed to do? If you want to forward something you should return either lvalue-ref or rvalue-ref. This is how forwarding is defined.

Comment: Ok, that is fair, its intended to used to eg. std::transform - to convert between types. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform. My actual case is to use with boost::range library for a range adapter. Maybe i can provide a small example, but dont have time now.